# Packaging trigger on UserTerritory2Association object (part of Enterprise Territory Management 2.0)

Tags: trigger, managed-package, territory-management, territory

Our managed package (1gp) has a dependency from *Enterprise Territory Management (ETM 2.0)*.
And we've created a trigger on **UserTerritory2Association** object to track moments when user is assigned to a territory or removed from it.

We were able to deploy this trigger successfully into packaging org, but it does not become a part of package automatically, i.e. based on our configuration in package.xml.

Also when we try to add it manually to the package from web UI, we don't see it available for selection (as well as it is not among already selected packaged components, but we can still see it in Setup->Apex Triggers section).

Is there some restriction re packaging such trigger? Are there any docs available where it's mentioned? Any other potential reason of such weird behaviour? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can manually edit or deploy anything in a managed package using package.xml or the UI (hence, the name "managed package"). For example, with flows in managed packages all you can do is enable or disable them, not even view the content. Pretty sure this is by design. Developers (selling you their app on the AppExchange) obviously don't want you to be able to see, edit, or reverse engineer their code, or have any control over it really, otherwise it would be an unmanaged package (open source/freeware).

Comment: The question is written by someone "selling you their app on the AppExchange" (potentially) and refers to a problem on the packaging org, not a subscriber org. You are referring to a subscriber org. Or have I overlooked anything?

Comment: @FelixvanHove, I see it the same way. Looks like the question is asked by the manage package's developer, so the answer may not be relevant.